# PHP foreach with session

Tags: php, foreach, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to show all pictures from a users Facebook login on my site.

If do this `($_SESSION['Photos']['data']['0']['source'])` in PHP it puts out the latest tagged image link. If it you replace the `0` with a `1`, it's the second latest tagged.

How do I make an `foreach` array where it adds '1' to the 0 each loop, according to how many `$_SESSION['Photos']['data']`'s there is?

Inside the loop I'm going to post the link into an `img` tag, and display all the tagged images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`for`](http://php.net/for) loop sounds more suitable, in this case:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION['Photos']['data']); $i++) { 
    echo $_SESSION['Photos']['data'][$i]['source'];
}
```

Comment: Why did you placed `)` in the end of line 2 ?

Comment: @Sultenhest: No worries :)